# Machine code instruction to jump to a specific address

Tags: x86, buffer-overflow, machine-code

I have a task to inject machine code instruction(in a stack overflow) the code injection aims to printf a message and continue with the normal flow of the program. I managed to get the printf correctly and exits. I now need to add the return address which the program should return to once the message is printed. I have been told to use a jmp instruction to jump to a specific address (raw address). does anyone know the correct machine instruction to do so?
the address I would like to jump to is 0x0804a21e

Comment: The technique you used to generate the other instructions for injection (presumably, looking them up in the manual and encoding them) should work for the `jmp` instruction too.

Comment: x86 doesn't have a direct absolute near jump.  So your options are: (1) use direct absolute far jump, opcode EA, only if in 32-bit mode and only if you know the correct value for the code segment CS. (2) load the address into a register or memory and use indirect near jump, opcode FF /4.  See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp

Comment: Another option is to push the address onto the stack and then `ret` (assuming you can safely write to the stack at this point).

Comment: If your payload knows the exact ESP address anyway, a `jmp rel32` can reach any desired target address.  But if you need a nop slide to avoid knowing the *exact* ESP for your injected code payload, you'd want to emulate an absolute jump with multiple instructions, like `push imm32` / `ret` being a good compact way since performance doesn't matter.